# Weighted count of words in string using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a string of words:

```
foo = "This is a string"
```

I also have a list that is formatted in the following way:

```
bar = ["this","3"], ["is","5"]
```

I need to make a script, that searches foo for words in bar, if a word is found, a counter should add the number next to the word in bar.
I have come this far:

```
bar_count=0
for a,b in foo:
   if bar in a:
       bar_count+=b
```

but this does not seem to work, anyone have any idea?

Comment: bar is not a list, it is a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted a total - convert `bar` into a `dict` and use that to look up valid words, and default unknown to `0` to run it through `sum`:

```
foo = "This is a string"
bar = ["this","3"], ["is","5"]
scores = {w: int(n) for w, n in bar}
bar_count = sum(scores.get(word, 0) for word in foo.lower().split())
# 8
```

If you wanted the count of words, but starting each from the total specified in `bar`:

```
from collections import Counter
start = Counter({w: int(n) for w, n in bar})
total = start + Counter(foo.lower().split())
# Counter({'is': 6, 'this': 4, 'a': 1, 'string': 1})
```

Comment: I think the list is supposed to be a list of weights, rather than starting count.

Comment: @Marcin agreed. I admit that initially I was basing it on "*if a word is found, a counter should add the number next to the word in bar.*" - but then figured from the code, we're counting words that have associated values. Figured it didn't hurt too much to leave it all in (after a few edits!)

Comment: I'll admit that I misread the question - I didn't realise it was looking for an aggregate count rather than per-word count.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dict to keep count;

```
foo = "This is a string"
words = foo.split()
count = {}
scores = {"this": 3,
          "is": 5
}

for word in words:
    if word not in count:
        count[word] = 0

    if word in scores:
        count[word] += scores[word]
    else:
        count[word] += 1
```

Comment: well that would increase the count by 1 everytime, wouldn't it?
I need the count increased by the number next to each word in bar.

Comment: @Shifu This would read over the words in foo and increment the relevant counter each time the word is seen. I've updated my answer for the scenario where you want words to have different scores.

Comment: I included `count[word] += 1` for cases where there was no score for the word. You could leave this out entirely if you do not wish to increase the score.

Comment: You could do `bar = sum(count.itervalues())` at the end if you just want a total, although @Jon Clements answer seems far more concise!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> foo = "This is a string string This bar"
>>> dic = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for f in foo.split():
...     dic[f] += 1
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'This': 2, 'a': 1, 'is': 1, 'bar': 1, 'string': 2})
```

EDIT

Create a dict out of this lists you have currently, a dict is a better representation of the data

```
>>> foo = 'this is a string this bar'
>>> bar = [['this', 3], ['is', 5]]
>>> dic = dict(bar)
>>> dict(bar)
{'this': 3, 'is': 5}
```

Now, look for words in your string and add stuff

```
>>> for f in foo.split():
...     try:
...         dic[f] += 1
...     except:
...         pass
>>> dic
{'this': 5, 'is': 6}
```

Does that help?

Comment: that makes it a ditcionary, but how do I then match it to foo?

Comment: @Shifu I misread your question. My apologies. But you should really consider converting your lists to a dictionary.

Comment: @Shifu If words are found that's not present in bar, do you need to increment the count?

Comment: no, that would not increment, or increment by 0.
Furthermore, your code gives me:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1):

This code will create a dictionary with found words as keys and value will be how many time the word did occur:

```
foo = "This is a string is is"
bar = {}

words = foo.split(" ")

for w in words:
    if(w in bar):
        # its there, just increment its value
        bar[w] += 1
    else:
        # its not yet there, make new key with value 1
        bar[w] = 1

for i in bar:
    print i,"->", bar[i]
```

This code yelds:

```
>>> 
This -> 1
a -> 1
is -> 3
string -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you case

```
foo = "This is a string"
bar = ["this","3"], ["is","5"]

bar_count = 0
for word, value in bar:
   if foo.count(word) > 0:
       bar_count += int(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses no explicit loops (apart from a comprehensions), and is, I think very easy to understand:

```
import collections
weight_list = ["this","3"], ["is","5"]
foo = "This is a string"

def weighted_counter(weight_list, countstring):
    #create dict {word:count of word}. uses lower() because that's
    # the format of the weight_list
    counts = collections.Counter(countstring.lower().split())

    #multiply weight_list entries by the number of appearances in the string
    return {word:int(weight)*counts.get(word,0) for word,weight in weight_list}

print weighted_counter(weight_list, foo)
#{'this': 3, 'is': 5}
#take the sum of the values (not keys) in the dict returned
print sum(weighted_counter(weight_list, "that is the this is it").itervalues())
#13
```

In action: http://ideone.com/ksdI1b